# When retrieving records from a MongoDb collection, do the records come back sorted based on the index that was set up for that collection?

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have a case that looks like this:
I have a collection called for example "Test" and I have set up an index for it and the index looks something like this:

```
{
 "A" : 1,
 "B" : 1,
 "C" : 1
}
```

In my code I am retrieving the records based on "A" being a certain value:

```
List<Test> tests = Test.Find(Query.EQ("A", CertainValue)).ToList();
```

And to my surprise all the records are coming back sorted in the order mentioned in the index ("B" ascending then "C" ascending)

I was wondering if this behavior is always to be expected, is the records always going to be sorted based on the index, or am I just imagining stuff and this is just a one off case?

PS. The Records are NOT entered into the collection sorted so this is not the natural order of the records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as with many other dictionary implementations, [order in database is not defined or guaranteed (except for capped collections)](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Sorting+and+Natural+Order) and subject to change at any time:

> "Natural order" is defined as the database's native ordering of
>   objects in a collection.
>
> When executing a find() with no parameters, the database returns
>   objects in forward natural order.
>
> For standard tables, natural order is not particularly useful because,
>   although the order is often close to insertion order, it is not
>   guaranteed to be. However, for Capped Collections, natural order is
>   guaranteed to be the insertion order.

Use explicit sort if you need them sorted in some way or refer to your particular driver (C#) implementation docs to see if it sorts them for you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did more experiment with how I retrieved the data from MongoDB and you were right, the order is not guaranteed. For example if I tried to find the records based on property "B" the result was sorted based on "C" but not "A". So I ended up sorting it myself: `Test.Find(Query.EQ("A", CertainValue)).SetSortOrder(SortBy.Ascending("B", "C")).ToList();`